# FQL - List comments of a post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-comments

I'm looking to run a competition on Facebook for my company by posting a question and entering the commenters into a random draw.

I was wondering if it was possible using either FQL or graph to list people who have commented on a particular post, along with the date of their comment?

Comment: I have, I can't see anything documented regarding accessing comments threads on posts - only with regard to accessing individuals. I was wondering if this was actually possible with FQL or graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), if you use the following

```
/me?fields=id,name,posts.limit(10).fields(comments)
```

You can access all the comments on the 10 recent posts. Tinker around - you'll find what you need.